# Android annotation upgrade to 4.0.0 build error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-annotations

After I update android annotation library version to 4.0.0 from 3.0+, I cannot build the application. My project can build successfully with android annotation 3.0+ but cannot with 4.0.0.
When I check the android annotation log file, it show the following errors repeatly(8 times).

```
11:57:33.458 [Daemon worker Thread 5] ERROR o.a.i.p.ModelValidator:74 - Unrecognized type. Please let your attribute be primitive or implement Serializable or Parcelable or an annotated Parceler bean.
11:57:33.459 [Daemon worker Thread 5] WARN  o.a.i.p.ModelValidator:85 - Element selectedContacts invalidated by ExtraHandler
```

All generated files from android annotation cannot generate because of this error, so, I could not manage to find the source of error. 
Could you please suggest me about what can be the source of this error?

Thanks.

Comment: post your complete build failure log please

Comment: Thanks I found the source of the problem, the problem is I used List instead of ArrayList on Extra field. Thanks for all comment and suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `selectedContacts` field. It has an `@Extra` annotation, but the type of the field is not correct for that annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is correct. I used List<Contact> on selectContacts variable but when I putExtraArrayList, this happen issue. But in old version it was OK :) Thanks

Comment: Yes, we are now only allow `ArrayList`, because `List` is not `Serializable`, so problems can happen at runtime.